# Update Bootstrap Thumbail Grid - ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

**Scenario:** I have a view with a twitter bootstrap thumbnail grid that shows the countries. When the user clicks one image, it is supposed to show the cities related to that country, in the same grid (screen).

**Technical:** First I fill the dataProvider with countries, and then I should send a ajax request with the country id to my controller where it queries the database for cities related to that country and sends the new dataProvider, back to the view where it updates the same thumbnail dataProvider with new data.

**Question:** How do I do this?

Here is my code:

view with thumbnail declaration (name of the view: _detail)

```
<?php 

            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbThumbnails', array(
            'id' => 'detailThumbnails',
            'dataProvider' => $dataprov,
            'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
            'itemView' => '_thumb',
            ));

        ?>
```

view called in thumbnail "itemView" property (name of the view: _thumb)

```
<?php
    require_once '_detail.php';
?>
<li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="<?php echo "thumbnail".$data['id']  ?>" rel="tooltip" data-title=" <?php echo "Clicar.."; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . $data['photo'] ?>" alt="">
        <a href=
           "
           <?php 
           echo $className;
           echo $this->createUrl(get_class($data).'/view', array('id' => $data['id'])); 

           ?>
           "
           >
               <?php 

               echo $data['name'].$data['id']; 
               ?>
        </a>

        <?php

        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('thumbClick'.$data['id'],'
                    $(".thumbnail'.$data['id'].'").click(function(){
                        var request = $.ajax({
                            data: {
                                id : '.$data['id'].'
                            },
                            type: "post",
                            url:"'.Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("tripDetail/getCities").'",
                            error: function(response, error)
                            {
                                alert("Error: " + response + " : " + error);
                            },
                        });
                        $(".thumbnail'.$data['id'].'").ajaxSuccess(function() {
                            $.fn.yiiListView.update("detailThumbnails");
                        });
                    });
                ');
        ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

In case of success i need to update the same dataProvider, which is in the view named _detail, hence the require_once. What iam trying to do is pass the data from controller(below) in json and decode here. But i don't know how to build a new data provider from the json response, and dont know either if the encode is properly made. Is it????

controller (just some functions)

```
public function actionCreate()
        {
            $session = new CHttpSession;
            $session->open();

            if(isset($_SESSION['mySession']))
            {
                $data = $_SESSION['mySession'];

                if ($data)
                {
                    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    {
                        $dataprov = new CActiveDataProvider("Country");
                        $this->render('create', 
                                array(
                                    'dat'=>$data,
                                    'dataprov'=>$dataprov
                                    )
                                );
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public function actionGetCities()
        {

            if(isset($_POST['id']))
            {
                $cityId = $_POST['id'];

                $dataProvider = $this->getCitiesFromDb($cityId);

                echo $this->renderPartial('_detail',array('dataprov'=> $dataProvider),true,true);   
            }
        }

        public function getCitiesFromDb($cityId)
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
            $criteria->select = "*";
            $criteria->condition = "b4_Country_id = " . $cityId;

            $dataProv = new CActiveDataProvider('City', 
                    array('criteria'=>$criteria));

            return $dataProv;
        }
```

If this is not the right way to do this, please let me know

Comment: This will not work `<?php$json = CJSON::decode(data)?>` since you're trying to mix server side code with client side paramteres. `data` is not accessible to php since it's a javascript variable.

Comment: Also there is no jQuery `update` method so this `$("#detailThumbnails").update(data);` won't do anything unless you've implemented a custom plugin named `update`. And you don't need to decode JSON manually on the client side, you can just add the `dataType: 'json'` as a parameter to the jquery `$.ajax` call or you can send json headers from php and jQuery will identify and parse the response as JSON: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Another problem is that when i click the image, it generates 2 requests to the server-side, since the script is registered in the _thumb view...

Comment: Can you clarify this line: "First i fill the dataProvider with *cities*, and then i should send a ajax request with the country id to my controller where it queries the database for cities related to that country". If you already have cities, then why query again?

Comment: Its countries, sorry....

Comment: The idea in the first place is having a thumbnail grid filled with countries, then when you click an image, it shows cities. if my line of though is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: The problem of generating 2 requests is solved. I just need to encode my dataprovider data (cities) that is related to the request (country) and sent it back to the view _thumb and update the dataprovider with the new data

Comment: How to encode data from dataProvider in json???

Comment: Ok, i resolved the last doubt. The 2 doubts remaining are: 1 - How can i update the dataProvider of the Thumbnails; 2 - Is all this procedure going to update the images that are rendered in the thumbnails?

Comment: from your comments to Afnan's answer, you got dataProvider should not be empty, at which line? and what did you do to remove that error?

Comment: The dataProvider was empty right in the first screen, i resolve sending it initialied from actionCreate in my Controller to the create view and from there to the _detail view where its used.

Comment: The problem is that when i click a country image, it should update to the correspondent cities and that doesnt happen

Comment: ok, fine did you check the result of the ajax call with firebug?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18729/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-luis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yesterday i fixed the problem that was in the jquery. The html generated was right but was not being inserted, when the image refreshed, and then, a little light turned on:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('thumbClick'.$data['id'],'
                    $(".thumbnail'.$data['id'].'").click(function(){
                        var request = $.ajax({
                            data: {
                                id : '.$data['id'].'
                            },
                            type: "post",
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#detailThumbnails").html(data);
                            },
                            url:"'.Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("tripDetail/getCities").'",
                            error: function(response, error)
                            {
                                alert("Error: " + response + " : " + error);
                            },
                        });
                    });
                ');
```

The part of the code that says "sucess: "

**Thank you very much for all the help you people gave me, specially bool.dev. Your help was precious.**

Comment: glad i could help out. good that you figured out your own solution

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `Server Side Code` and `Client side code`.

---

**Server Side Code**

---

This code resides on server and upon request it gets executed to provide the valid output to the client. Once it is done it does not maintains any connection with the client

---

**Client Side code**

---

Once request is sent to server client waits for response from server and receives anything sent from server. Once done it disconnects from server until further requests made by user or scripts.

What you did here is `<?php$json = CJSON::decode(data)?>` php tags are serverside thing and they can not be populated because they appear on client side as in your code. Consider following

If you successfully made the `AJAX` request you better try changing `datatype` of `Ajax request`. I guess you are half way there but you do not know how to decode the `JSON` received. you can use `'dataType'=>'json'` in your ajax request. for more details see [Updating fields with Ajax and Json](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/164/updating-fields-on-a-form-with-ajax-and-json/)

Hopes this makes life easier

As for update part you can do something like create page and call it via `renderpartial` and return `HTML` to your view

```
public function actionGetCities()
        {

            if(isset($_POST['id']))
            {
                $cityId = $_POST['id'];

                $dataProvider = $this->getCitiesFromDb($cityId);
                echo $this->renderPartial('updateView',array('dataprovider'=> $dataProvider),true,true);//see documentation for third and fourth parameter and change if you like   
            }
        }
```

and in your view you can just update the div that initially have the orignal grid so no need to use `json` format.
**updateView**

```
<?php 
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbThumbnails', array(
                'id' => 'detailThumbnails',
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
                'itemView' => '_thumb',
            ));

        ?>
```

> Note:
>   This code is not tested and is given for an idea only.

Comment: First, i want to thank you for your answer. I've changed the code but the problem is that i cannot update the dataProvider, like i said in my last comment...

Comment: there are different workarounds but you would not be able to update `'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,` property because it is server side code. What you can do is get your action to generate `html` use `renderPartial` in your action and in the pass the new dataprovider and get html from there and show. see raw code formation in answer

Comment: I get your point, but... :( still doesnt work. Let me ask you something. If you were to put the first dataProvider initialization, where do you do it??

Comment: luis, what data is being returned from server? what is the error? is the url getting called correctly?

Comment: I updated the code. Now it throws an exception since the dataProvider is updated via ajax in the first place...

Comment: The code is updated. Now, when i click an image, it doesnt show anything, but refreshes the screen but the images are missing. The exception was  The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.

Comment: Just a note: The images that are missing are the supposed Cities that were to come up with the screen refreshing

Comment: I guess you missed the initial thing see it works like the action i told you is for update thing not first. if you have to display once you need to initiliaze. Make differnt actions one for first time display and other for ajax update. Use fire bug or F12 and then network tab to see the requests and their errors